# How to read contents on a local file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file

I want to start off by saying that I do not think this is a duplicate because any other question I’ve found of this nature is based on getting the files contents from a document.getElement tag where the user is choosing a file and going from there. I’m trying to read in a file that is in a folder on my computer. In my C drive. I haven’t been able to find anything along these lines and would appreciate any help or being  pointed in the right direction. I am trying to find out if this is possible or not using raw v8 js.

Comment: You haven't found anything because this is not possible. JS hasn't access to the local filesystem, the only way is `<input type="file">`.

Comment: The right direction is to protect any file on your computer to not be read by any script on any site))

Comment: If it's a back-end application, are you using Node or some other JS/native environment? If so, please include that in your tags and your question, because that is important information.

Comment: Backend? There's no word about backend in your question ... If you've a nodejs app, then store the files to a folder inside your node installation folder.

Comment: And you think it's not a worth of mention in the question?

Comment: In python and java you would still read the file differently depending on it's location.
Is it a user file, to be uploaded? Is it a file on your disk outside of the sourcecode that you want to copy? Is it contained within your source repository and thus can just be imported? 

Also in JS there are multiple different runtimes, if you are frontend then there is no way of reading a file without the `input` tag uploading it, but if you are backend and have access to the node.js libraries you can use the `fs` file-loading tool.

Comment: JavaScript is run in an environment, there's no kind of IO methods in JS, it even can't output anything without an environment.

Comment: We know how to read files in node / electon environments, and in browser environments. You can probably find out how to read files in other environments like chrome and vscode extensions. However, we don't know any way of reading a file in "a TFC library running raw v8 JavaScript". The way of reading files depends on what it being run in, so you need some sort of API that let's you access files with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the context, and where the file is currently located.

For a user-specified file, your only way of accessing that is asking the user to upload it via a `<input type="file">` input element.

For a backend file (ie on your machine), in JS there are multiple different runtimes, all of which have different methods of importing or referencing local files.

You mention in a comment that you're using "raw" JS via the V8 engine, which doesn't have any capabilities for accessing local files.

However, if you set up access to the Node.js ecosystem of libraries you can use the `fs` file-loading tool, like so:

```js
fs.readFile('filepath', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

(docs [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html))

Comment: None of the solutions in this answer answer the problem, because @Luke said "I’m not using node or any other framework." He also said in the question that he isn't going to use `<input type="file">`.

Comment: They answer the overall question, which is what future people will come across via google.
Further details were added in comments since I wrote this answer, but depending on what is meant by a "TFC library running raw v8 JavaScript", it could be possible that loading `fs` is still possible, or if just running raw js there are no file system apis, which I have added into that answer.